# I installed blender on linux, and by default OpenImageDenoise is not enabled, how to enable it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, installation, linux, denoise

Like the title states, i have installed blender on linux and everything works fine, except for the OpenImageDenoise, i am sure that my computer does support that feature as when i use blender on windows it works fine, why does it not work on the linux version?
The node is there but it just says "disabled, built without openimagedenoise"

Comment: The node for the compositor is shipped with blender so there is nothing to enable. Make sure your blender version is above [2.81](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-81/#intel-open-image-denoise) to get OpenImageDenoise (working fine for me on arch linux). I guess you mean the [OptiX denoiser](https://www.blendernation.com/2020/02/13/blender-features-update-optix-viewport-denoising-added-to-2-83/) for the viewport... Consider that you need a cuda card for that along with its latest drivers as well as Blender 2.83.

Comment: that is the issue, i have blender 2.82 and openimagedenoise doesnt work, it is there but it just says "built without open image denoise"

Comment: Official version of Blender 2.8x is built with OpenImageDenoise so... make sure you are running an official build from blender.org: https://www.blender.org/download/ Otherwise please add more detail to your question...

Comment: i did install from blender.org

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this error on Ubuntu. I went to the Ubuntu Software app and realized there were two Blender packages, and the one I had installed was from the ubuntu-groovy-universe source, which was on an old version. Use the one from the snapcraft.io source. Switching made this work for me.

Comment: I'd recommend always download from: https://www.blender.org/download/