# Cycles cant render because of openimage denois

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am using blender 3.4 version and I couldn't render my image in cycles . I enable the denoise button in render tab and when i finally render in cycles its showing as error "built without openimage denoise"

But when I disable the denoise buttons and render the image renders but the output is full of noise and blurry

Comment: Hello! Can you please provide a .blend file?

Comment: I don't think a blend file will help. It sounds you have downloaded a custom Blender version that was build without the OpenImage denoise. Have you downloaded Blender from the official site or do do you use Linux? Here is a similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178315/i-installed-blender-on-linux-and-by-default-openimagedenoise-is-not-enabled-ho

Comment: Yes I use Linux Debian 12